# Move a program launcher across computers (Xubuntu)

Tags: xubuntu, xfce-panel

I have a program launcher in the xfce panel of my old computer that holds a number of individual launchers to deal with dual screens (one item turns my monitor horizontal, another one turns it vertically, one more turns my laptop monitor off, another one on, etc).

I don't want to have to create this program launcher anew in my new computer.  Is there a way of copying/exporting a program launcher so that I can be spared of just having to add each of these items and to retype all of the commands from scratch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be a more elegant solution, but this one worked for me.

1. Find the program launcher in your old computer.

You can find all of your program launchers in `$HOME/.config/xfce4/panel/`  Each launcher, at least in my system, falls within a folder called "launcher-10", "laucher-11", etc.  The one I want to copy is called "launcher-10"

Look for the folder which hosts the launcher which you are interested in copying.  (If you are not sure which one is it, open the files within each of these folders with a text editor.  Taking a look at this file will allow you to know which item each is, and to which launcher it belongs).

2. Copy the program laucher to the new computer.

Copy this folder (in my case "launcher-10") to the panel of your new system.  Just paste the launcher you want onto: `$HOME/.config/xfce4/panel/`

This might be enough.  When you reboot (or perhaps only when you log out, I did not try this out), the new program program launcher(s) might just pop up in your panel.

3. If you don't want to reboot, or if this does not work...

Create a program launcher manually from your new panel (right click on the panel and click for "add new items...").  Notice what the name of the folder corresponding to this new program launcher is in `$HOME/.config/xfce4/panel/`  and just copy all the files from the old launcher into this new folder.

I hope this helps other folks. It took me a while, and some serendipity, to figure it out.

Comment: A *program* launcher, are you sure OP does not mean an edited `.desktop` file form `~/.local/share/applications`?

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your question.  What is OP?

Comment: OP = original poster (SaMeji) , but obviously you were correct :) I see the answer was accepted in the meantime. +1 !